# Making a conditional statement in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, package-writing

I am trying to make a style file for me to simplify note-taking, especially subjects involving Math.

I want to make the `\delim` command, having one mandatory argument for the expression, and an optional argument to change the delimiter using the characters from the `matrix` commands from `amsmath`, which are `(p), [b], {B}, |v|, ||V||` with `p` as the default.

I think it will involve `\if` commands, but I don't know how to check if the optional argument is `p`, `b`, `B`, `v`, or `V`. Any help is  much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Disclaimer: My personal opinion is that while this *might* make typing faster, it renders the code far less readable.)

Here is a way: first I define a bunch of paired delimiters by means of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, which provides for all of them a stared version which scales automatically, and an optional argument to give the size manually; then I introduce the user macro which selects the desired delimiters through an optional argument

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\delim@}{\delim@p}% better safe than sorry
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\delim@p}{(}{)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\delim@b}{[}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\delim@B}{\{}{\}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\delim@v}{|}{|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\delim@V}{\|}{\|}
\newcommand*{\delim}[1][p]{\csname delim@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\delim{a+b},
\delim[b]{a+b},
\delim*{\frac{1}{2}},
\delim[B]*{\frac{1}{2}},
\delim[v][\Bigg]{\frac{1}{2}},
\delim[][\Big]{a+b},% or \delim[p][\Big]{a+b}
\delim[F]{a+b}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first optional argument is `p`, `b`, and so on. Then you can write a star for automatic scaling, or give the manual size as further optional parameter.

Check out the last two cases: if you want to give *only* the manual size with round brackets then the first optional parameter should either be empty or be an explicit `p`. Furthermore, there is no test on `p`, `b`, ... If you misspell it, nothing meaningful comes out: `\delim[F]{a+b}` gives just `a+b`.

---

If you really want to see how a bunch of nested `\if`s would look like, you could do

```
\newcommand*{\delim}[1][p]{%
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \if#1p\relax
   \else
      \if#1b\relax
      \else
         \if#1B\relax
         \else
            \if#1v\relax
            \else
               \if#1V\relax
               \else
                  \def\@tempa{p}% if none of pbBvV then fall back to p
               \fi
            \fi
         \fi
      \fi
   \fi
   \csname delim@\@tempa\endcsname
}
```

which would give parentheses in case of a misspelled/empty argument.

Comment: Is there a way that is something like ```if arg = p then```? Your MWE is beyond my expectations, but I can't understand it quite well.

Comment: @soupless I'm not sure I understand the question. It would be possible to write a bunch of nested `\if`s but I thought this to be a more efficient approach.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I kind of expected: a bunch of nested `\if`s. Can you give a simple example, like only for `p` and `b`? If so, kindly add it in your answer. Just starting so I kind of sticks to the familiar ways :)

Comment: It makes sense now that it is inefficient, but this will be a learning opportunity for me.

Comment: I forgot to ask this question, but is it okay to write `\if#1p` as `\if{#1}{p}`?

Comment: @soupless Absolutely not. `\if` expands tokens until it finds two non expandable tokens and compares them. Braces are also tokens and would interfere with this mechanism.

Comment: @soupless To expand on my last comment: try `\if{p}{p}TRUE\else FALSE\fi` and you'll be surprised. `\if` compares `{` and `p`, the comparison is of course false, and the rest up to `\else` is discarded. It would be worse with `\if{{p}}{{p}}TRUE\else FALSE\fi`: then the two `{` would be compared, and you get troubles with mismatched `}`.